# When Partial view loads my Main view Select2 is not a function error

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery-select2

In my asp.net MVC application, I'm using the select2 combo box.

When I select a value from the combo box and hit the save button, the record will be passed to the controller via Javascript and bring bag the saved results and load it in the partial view below the combo box.

So whenever the partial view is loaded, my main view combo box error occurs as `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).Select2 is not a function`

Is someone knows how to fix this issue?

This is my current code

```
 <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="tab_content3" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">
   <div class="x_panel"> @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" }) 
    <form id="frmStaffAssign">
       <div class="row"> @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.TaskDetailsList.First().Id, new { @id = "taskId" }) 
         <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
           <div class="form-group row"> @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TaskAssignViewModel.Branch_Id, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" }) <div class="col-sm-8"> @Html.DropDownList("Branch_Id", null, "Select the Branch", new { @class = "form-control js-dropdown js-BranchAssign", @Id = "BranchAssign" }) </div>
           </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
           <div class="form-group row"> @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TaskAssignViewModel.Emp_Id, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" }) <div class="col-sm-8"> @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.TaskAssignViewModel.Emp_Id, new List <SelectListItem>(), "Select Staff Member", new { @class = "form-control js-dropdown js-Member", @id = "ddlEmpIdAssign" }) </div>
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="UpdateTaskAssigned();">Assign Task</button>
     </form>
   </div>
   <div id="PartialViewAssignedH"> @{ Html.RenderPartial("_TaskAssignedHistory"); } </div>
 </div>
```

Javascript

```
 function GetBranchMembers(xVal) {

   try {

     $("#ddlEmpIdAssign").empty().trigger("changed");
     $.ajax({
       url: '../GetBranchMembers',
       type: 'POST',
       dataType: 'json',
       cache: false,
       async: false,
       data: {
         Id: xVal
       },
       success: function (data) {
         if (data.Success == true) {

           $("#ddlEmpIdAssign").select2({
             width: '100%',
             data: JSON.parse(data.items)
           });
         }
       }
     });

   } catch (err) {
     console.log(err.message)
   }
 }
```

In the Main view I have these

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.6.1.min.js"></script>
<link href="~/Addons/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Addons/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please make sure the script path is correct or file is available in this location.

Comment: @AmitGupta script paths are correct.

Comment: This type of error only occurs only when file is not referred correctly. If you look at the error it is saying, Select2 is not a function, it means JavaScript is trying to call Select2 function but not able to find it.

Comment: Do you set the `<script>` and  Javascript at the same view ? If not, try to put them together.

Comment: @AmitGupta Yes. Only issue is when this error comes and I refresh the page, then it working. When Partial view is loaded, then this error comes.

Comment: @QingGuo Yes. they all all in the same view.